# Airmon-ng confliciting with network manager in Kali

Tags: wireless, kali-linux

When starting monitor mode on wlan0 using `airmon-ng start wlan0` I got a list of processes 'including network manager' that could cause troubles.
I must kill those processes before starting `airbase-ng --essid network -c 6 wlan0mon` or I will have this error:

```
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Operation not supported
ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.  Make
sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start wlan0mon <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found either.
```

Killing the process network manager solves the problem, but I need the network manager for further Ettercap activites.

So, anyway to fix the confilicting between network-manager and airmon-ng ?

Comment: Why do you need NM for Ettercap? Just manually configure the interfaces and point Ettercap at them.

Comment: When the NM falls down, every interface like eth0 lose their iIPs and configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because NM is set to control **all** your interfaces. So when you kill NM you kill all the interfaces.

You have two approaches, disable NM completely and manually configure your interfaces individually or allow NM to control all the interfaces apart from the wireless one you want to use with airmon.

Depending on the distro depends on how you do this. If the distro is red hat based then typically you just put 
`NM_CONTROLLED=no` in the interface config file at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-wlan0`.

But as your distro is Kali and debian based then add the wlan interface to`/etc/network/interfaces.` config file and NM will ignore it.

For example;

```
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 10.10.168.1
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        gateway 10.10.168.10
```

Then restart both the networking and network manager daemons with `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart && service network-manager restart`

Or you can configure network manager directly to ignore the interface by editing `/etc/NetworkManager` with the following.

```
[main]
plugins=keyfile

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:*your wlan interface mac address here*
```

Comment: your answer is correct, also I've found another way: 
`airmon-ng start wlan0 `  `ifconfig wlan0mon down`  `iwconfig wlan0mon mode monitor`   `ifconfig wlan0mon up`